# SQL simplication

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
       (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS
                   (SELECT *
                    FROM votes
                    WHERE votes.user_id = 0
                      AND votes.post_id = posts.id
                      AND votes.vote = 0) THEN 0
            WHEN EXISTS
                   (SELECT *
                    FROM votes
                    WHERE votes.user_id = 0
                      AND votes.post_id = posts.id
                      AND votes.vote = 1) THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END) AS vote_by_me ,
       posts.*
FROM `posts`
```

Is there a way I can do this in a DRY manner? Both select statements are almost the same, would be nice to factor them out some way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can select `votes.vote` directly, like this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT MIN(votes.vote)
        FROM votes
        WHERE votes.user_id = 0 AND votes.post_id = posts.id
        AND votes.vote in (0, 1)
        GROUP BY votes.user_id, votes.post_id
        )
    ,   2
    ) AS vote_by_me
,   posts.*
FROM `posts
```

If a post cannot have multiple votes by the same user, you could eliminate the `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT votes.vote
        FROM votes
        WHERE votes.user_id = 0 AND votes.post_id = posts.id AND votes.vote in (0, 1)
        )
    ,   2
    ) AS vote_by_me
,   posts.*
FROM `posts
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I used the latter because post cannot have multiple votes by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to simplify the query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN v.votes0 > 0 THEN 0
             WHEN v.votes1 > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 2
        END) AS vote_by_me,
       p.*
FROM posts p left outer join
     (select v.post_id, sum(v.vote = 1) as vote1, sum(v.vote = 0) as vote0
      from votes v
      where v.user_id = 0
      group by v.post_id
     ) v
     on p.post_id = v.post_id;
```

The bad news is that if you have an index on `votes(user_id, post_id, votes)` then your original form will probably have better performance.

EDIT:

The following formulation might perform well and sort-of simplify the query:

```
SELECT (CASE (SELECT min(vote)
              FROM votes
              WHERE votes.user_id = 0 AND
                    votes.post_id = posts.id
             )
             WHEN 0 then 0
             WHEN 1 then 1
             ELSE 2
        END) AS vote_by_me,
       posts.*
FROM `posts`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
       (CASE                
            WHEN EXISTS
                   (SELECT *
                    FROM votes
                    WHERE votes.user_id = 0
                      AND votes.post_id = posts.id
                      AND votes.vote IN (0,1) )THEN votes.vote
            ELSE 2
        END) AS vote_by_me ,
       posts.*
FROM `posts`
```